# How to create a new playlist

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

How to create a smart playlist using objective-C for mac os x. I want to create a up/down button under that button i want to create new playlist. i dont know how to create a new folder or playlist in the application at run time.

Comment: your question is too wide, and we have no idea what are you talking about :). Try to be more specific, and give us some details

Comment: Playlist is the list of selected songs.

Answer (score 0):

You need some sort of representation of the data ie. an array. Then manipulate that data and display it however you want.

Your question is so wide it can be answered 200 diff. ways and no one wants to write all that code for you.

Go to http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLE83F832121568D36 and watch the videos

**Update:**

iTunes playlists are just tab delimited txt files or M3U files. Try creating a playlist in iTunes and right-click and press "export". Choose the file format you need. Open the newly created file to see how it's structured. You then create a program that can save a file in this syntax and format. The code is too much to do here. You can find an XML file containing all the music in the library in iTunes folder to help you get information on what contents there is to choose from.

Comment: actually i asked two question... i want to know 1) How to create a smart playlist (open iTunes-->File-->New Smart Playlist). 2) How to create a simple playlist (Open iTunes-->click on the left down (+) button)... any link or sample code...

Comment: could you please explain in detail...am not able to find any link or sample code related to this...am using AVAudioPlayer... am importing the song by xml file

Comment: What exactly do you need details on?

Comment: I am creating the child using NSOutlineView and setting them as simple and smart playlist on the basis of some conditions. i don't know this is a right way or not but i don't have any other solution.